# How to override Shaka player version using new API released March 31, 2022?

Tags: google-cast-sdk, shaka

Google released [new version CAST SDK March 31, 2022](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes#march-31,-2022) with ability for overriding Shaka Player version (as release notes said :) ) but it didn't provide documentation **how to set the Shaka Player version**
[image: release notes]

That is all what [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.PlaybackConfig) has about `cast.framework.PlaybackConfig#shakaConfig`

[image: existent documentation]

No any information about setting Shaka version at the moment.
Has anybody faced with a topic? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CastReceiverOptions` object has an undocumented field `shakaVersion`. Simply set to e.g. "4.2.2".

Comment: Yes, Google corrected the documentation and added the description how to change the `shakaVersion`https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.CastReceiverOptions#shakaVersion